# Re-creating Blocks Page for Content Authoring?

Tags: nodes

I'm using Drupal 7.14, and the biggest complaint I get from people new to Drupal is visualizing where the content goes once its created.

It got me thinking of some clever/native ways to do this with the base installation. I looked into the Overlay module that the administrators have access to, then Blocks page, then Context page, and none seem to provide an easy to use interface for doing what I want. I remember the Themer module in Drupal 6 highlighted the regions in the Blocks page when you're moving components around, and my question begs whether or not this can easily be re-created somehow?

Now I'm familiar that Drupal 8 + Sparks helps with content authoring a bit, I've seen the demo's where users can edit content on the page/layout, but it still doesn't allow for adding new ccks, nodes to a specific region on a page.

I'm not sure this is an appropriate D.SE question, but has anyone heard of a module, or can think of a way to provide a GUI for users to attach their newly created content to the specific region in a theme, most preferably when they are creating the content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [nodeblock](https://drupal.org/project/nodeblock) and [node-level-blocks](https://drupal.org/project/node_level_blocks) modules may be a good starting point.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this - reading through some of the node-level-blocks led me to the Bean module. I have limited experience with JavaBeans, so I'll explore if its similar. I'm not sure I have my answer yet, but I'll explore what you sent!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this on a node-by-node basis, the [Panels In-Place Editor](https://drupal.org/project/panels) (IPE - part of the **Panels** project) will do exactly that.